# Builder 4.5: How to change the colour of unoccupied space on a mobile actionscript project?

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

How do I change the colour of the space that my flash game doesn't occupy on a mobile device? Sorry for the newbie question but I think the plain white sides are not very good.

Comment: Why don't you cover them with something? Voted down.

Comment: @BotMaster How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try placing this below your import entries in the main class:

```js
    [SWF(backgroundColor='#ff0000',frameRate='50')]
```

For example,

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageDisplayState;
    import flash.display.StageQuality;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.ui.Multitouch;
    import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;


    [SWF(backgroundColor='#ff0000',frameRate='50')]

    public class MyApp extends Sprite
    {
        ...
```

This will give you a solid red background for the app, and a frameRate of 50!

Comment: :( It doesn't work. The game is still still sitting ontop of a white screen